# Can I change difficulty level or mode without starting over?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I'm on Hard / Classic mode, and my units are dying **a lot**.  Classic mode = permadeath, so my units are gone forever, and this is becoming frustrating. Can I change to a different difficulty level or mode without starting over?

Comment: Have you gone through the Options menu in the game?

Comment: If a unit dies you can always restart the mission to get them back. They are only gone forever if you complete the mission with them dead.

Comment: @AdamP - Yeah, I must have restarted one mission 15 times...

Comment: @KatieK such is Fire Emblem. It is nothing if not unforgiving.

Comment: One thing I've learned is to use Frederick and Kellam as secondaries in Pair Up; they boost Defense by several points, which will help survivability immensely.

Comment: I'm much happier since I restarted in Casual mode.  ;)

Comment: I will say that I'm happy I stuck with Hard/Classic despite it being extremely frustrating for the first 5 or 6 chapters.  I tend to focus on unit advancement and nearing the end of the game things have gotten a little too easy, even on Hard.  On normal I'd be bored by now.

Comment: I noticed on normal, you can easily buy a Reekbox for 500 gold, use it to summon the Risen on the map tile you're currently standing on, then fight them for 2 small bullions (which can be sold for 2000 gold in total) and 1 or 2 random weapons (+ any random item found on the two sparkling tiles) meaning you'll never lack money. Assuming Hard mode has it too, the most difficult part would be surviving the first few chapters. After that, one could easily farm Risen and money and make the Hard difficulty rather easy.

Comment: @Nolonar - On Hard mode, a Reeking Box costs 2400g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it can't. You'll have to restart the game to change difficulty.

Comment: This is correct.